# How to access docker compose mounted volume from inside the container

Tags: docker, volume, mount

I am mounting a local file inside a docker container through the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    myapp:
        build:
            context: ./dockerfiles
            dockerfile: myapp.Dockerfile
            args:
                - UID=1000
                - GID=1000
        network_mode: host
        volumes:
            - ./volumes/logs:/opt/myapp/logs
```

The mounted folder belongs to my user(uid: 1000, gid:1000) and these are the ids that the docker user gets, but the docker user cannot write to the mounted folder (`permission denied`).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000

RUN yum -y update && \
    yum -y install epel-release && \
    yum -y install passwd curl jq supervisor iputils openssl-devel
RUN yum -y clean all

RUN useradd -m -s /bin/sh user && \
    passwd -d user && \
    usermod -o -u ${UID} user && \
    groupmod -o -g ${GID} user

VOLUME ["/opt/myapp/logs"]

ADD myapp /opt/myapp/app
ADD supervisor/services.ini /etc/supervisord.d/services.ini
ADD start.sh /

RUN chown -R user:user /opt/myapp
RUN chown user:user /start.sh

USER user
CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

start.sh

```
exec supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf -n
```

service.ini

```
[program:myapp]
user = user
autorestart = true
stdout_logfile = /dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 0
stderr_logfile = /dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0
command = /opt/myapp/app
```

My `app` is run with `user` and it cannot write it's logs in the mounted folder.
My goal is to access the logs from outside the docker container.

> Even if I run with the `root` user inside the container, I still cannot access the mounted folder!